# Why i can't delete rows from this view that has aggregate function in select clause (ORACLE)?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, aggregate-functions

I've already read about rules for DML operations with views in ORACLE. Most of them seems clear to me, but i'm confused about aggregate function.

For example, I have two tables.

```
               EMPLOYEES
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║   emp_id  ║   salary    ║  dept_id ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║   2134    ║   2200      ║    10    ║
║   2327    ║   3100      ║    10    ║
║   2428    ║   4100      ║    20    ║
║   2637    ║   1700      ║    30    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
      \ | /
       \|/
        |
        |    DEPARTMENTS
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════╗
║ dept_id   ║   dname     ║ location ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════╣
║    10     ║             ║          ║
║    20     ║             ║          ║
║    30     ║             ║          ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════╝
```

I want a view that shows average employee salary by department.
So, i run this SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dept_sals AS
    SELECT d.dept_id, round(avg(e.salary)) AS avg_salary
    FROM employees e
      JOIN
         departments d
      ON (e.dept_id = d.dept_id)
    GROUP BY d.dept_id;
```

Now i have a view that looks like:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╗
║ dept_id   ║ avg_salary ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║    10     ║    2650    ║
║    20     ║    4100    ║
║    30     ║    1700    ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

I understand why i can't run update statements against this view. Column "avg_salary" is not a data, it is a dynamically generated information. But why i can't delete a row from this view?

If i try to run:

```
delete from dept_sals where dept_id = 10;
```

I get:

```
ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
```

What i'm thinking:

Base table DEPARTMENTS has a one-to-one relationship with rows in this view. 
I guess Oracle can get {dept_id} from view and generate SQL that deletes corresponding row from DEPARTMENTS table. This would not damage tables consistency as information in "avg_salary" is not a data, it's a calculations that we can throw away as department with {dept_id} is not exists anymore.

Comment: Deleting from  that view would logically delete rows from multiple tables or just one in your opinion? Though that isn't the answer as it would be prohibited even for a single table grouped query.

Comment: @Martin Smith I'm trying to figure out how Oracle views work because i don't understand the reason of delete restriction in this situation. I have tested a case when a view with SQL = two tables join, had both primary keys from base tables in it's rows: one-to-one and one-to-many. I could delete rows from that view and they actually were deleted from table that had one-to-one relationship. Base table with one-to-many relation with view was not affected with delete. I can't figure why Oracle can't do the same thing to example with avg. sals. I think he doesn't need employees table to do this.

Comment: In my opinion, Oracle didn't calculate all possible situations (there are very many possible situations with selects in view queries) and just put some baseline rules that separate updatable and non-updatable views, to mitigate this Oracle created INSTEAD OF triggers to make any such view (if it is necessary) updatable.

Answer (score 5):

What you are specifing is a non-updatable view in Oracle. Rules that separate updatable and non-updatable views is specified here from Oracle documenation.

"A view cannot be modified by UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements if the view query contains any of the following constructs:

```
A set operator

A DISTINCT operator

An aggregate or analytic function

A GROUP BY, ORDER BY, MODEL, CONNECT BY, or START WITH clause

A collection expression in a SELECT list

A subquery in a SELECT list

A subquery designated WITH READ ONLY

Joins, with some exceptions, as documented in Oracle Database Administrator's Guide"
```

link --> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm

What you want can be and is solved by using Oracle INSTEAD OF triggers.